# Reading MS Publisher Files?

Tags: c#, office-interop, publisher, ms-publisher

Has anyone seen a way to read/update the text in a Microsoft Office Publisher file (.pub)?

I don't think Open XML supports that. The only way I found so far would be via Office Interop, but that is not a good solution on the server.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Generally speaking, trying to read any Microsoft format is not easy because its all backwards compatible and thus extremely convoluted.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server workaround: www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Uses office interop, but is the only solution available since there is no public spec for the .pub format.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I figured there might be no good solution. The problem with Office Interop is, that it does not work in from a service anymore. It was called "Interactive Mode" before. The workaround then was to have a normal App running and controlling it via Messages. But it's cumbersome and instable.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/os_binaryfile/thread/63dc6c4e-d6b2-4873-97dd-139ddb304e24/) there is no support for the .pub format...